# Recommendations for PostgreSQL training

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for recommendations for PostgreSQL training (on-site, off-site, remote) that covers administration, performance optimization, and clustering solutions like Slony and pgpool.  Finding courses via web searches hasn't gotten me very far as it seems many of the linked pages are out of date, and where they are updated, I'm not sure how to judge the quality of the course they offer.  Does anyone have recommendations for courses they took, had colleagues take, or themselves teach?

Comment: If you don't have much luck here, ask on the pgsql-general mailing list. Personally I suspect independent learning is often better. EDB offers training, though I have no knowledge of or opinion on its quality: http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/training/dba-training

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the kind of question that is on-topic here. Good luck with the search :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best to start with is http://www.postgresql.org/docs/manuals/

These are really well written and cover everything you will need to know that is PostgreSQL specific.

Comment: Despite the phrasing, I tend to agree. Comprehensively reading the online documentation - and experimenting in `psql` as you go - will teach you a lot. Not only about PostgreSQL, but about SQL and databases in general.